# How to remove badge when x mark is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I have modal, in the modal there is a text field and an add-experience-button.

Now when I type "travel" in the textfield and click the add experience button, it will add a badge/chip on the div.

this is my javascript code:

```js
//remove chip when the x mark is click
  $(".remove-chip").on("click", e => {
    console.log("naclick");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement).remove();
  });
  //add chip when the add experience button is click
  $(".add-experience-button").on("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let experience = $("#experience-description").val();
    $(".experience-list-container").append(`
      <div class='chip'>
        <span class="uk-badge chip-badge">${experience}<span class="remove-chip">&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;</span></span>
      </div>
    `);
    $("#experience-description").text('');
  });
```

why $(".remove-chip").on("click") event is not working?

Comment: show the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove-chip", e => {
    console.log("naclick");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement).remove();
  });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/4ca2387b/12/) is the working demo.

You can try this as well:

```
$(".experience-list-container").on("click", ".remove-chip", e => {
    console.log("naclick");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement).remove();
  });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/4ca2387b/14) with parent class ref.

Comment: sir it did not clear the field after clicking the add button

Comment: Can you add it to a jsfiddle so that I can look into it.

Comment: I just move the e.preventDefault() after the $("#experience-description").val('');
now its okay. thanks again sir